# RegExp to select all but certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a phrase which might have 0 or more embedded strings in it like so: 
"THIS IS 0lsdkfjl0MY 1lsdkfjl0SENTENCE". 
The pattern of these embedded strings matches the expression:
(?:0|1)lsdkfjl(?:0|1|2|3|4). I need convert all the characters except those that match the pattern to lower case. How can I do this?
That's in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups and a replacement function:

```
str.replace(/[^dontmatch]+/g, function(match) {
    return match.toLowerCase();
});
```

Here's an example:

```
> 'ADFGXYZ'.replace(/[^AD]+/g, function(match) { return match.toLowerCase(); });
"ADfgxyz"
```

Comment: this is what I am trying to do, but the string that I need to skip is not a set blab of characters. As I said it has a pattern to it. So I can't say str.replace(/[^(?:0|1)lsdkfjl(?:0|1|2|3|4)]+/g, ...), can I?

Comment: @user1988833: Why don't you select the exact opposite? `([^01](?:.*?)[^0-4])`.

Comment: This doesn't work either. These are not just digits that I am trying to omit. It's a pattern that starts with a digit and ends with a digit, but any character used in that pattern but not in exact that sequence should be matched
so if I have 0lsdkfjl4 - that should be skipped, but just lsdkfjl should not

Comment: @user1988833: If the digits are the only things you care about, why don't you convert the entire string to lowercase?